# Design to place span immediately after line clamped div

Tags: css, angularjs, scss-mixins

I am creating a list item which will be clamped after two lines and will show ellipsis. This much is fine, but the tricky part is that after the ellipsis i have to put a pill. The pill comes fine if the text is of single line length. When the text moves to line 2 but not of full length  then the pill moves to line 3. Is there any way to keep the pill at the end of the text.

```css
li > span >  a {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    visibility: visible;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

```html
<li ng-repeat="parent in ctrl.objectiveCopy.parents track by parent.id" class="text-navy p-t-xxs font-weight-700 line-height-12">
      <span class="bullet-spacing-sm">
        <a class="text-navy" ng-if="!ctrl.readOnlyMode" ui-sref="main.objective_detail({Id: parent.id, entityId: parent.entity.id, entityType: parent.entity.type})">{{parent.title}}</a>
        <a class="text-navy cursor-unset" ng-if="ctrl.readOnlyMode">{{parent.title}}</a>
        <span ng-if="ctrl.showWeights && ctrl.objectiveCopy.weights[parent.id] !== 1.0" class="popover-weight-pill">
          <weight-pill weight="ctrl.objectiveCopy.weights[parent.id]" class="d-inline-block m-l-xs"></weight-pill>
        </span>
      </span>
</li>
```

current output
[image: Current output]
expected output

I want the 2x at the end of the text and not in the next line.

Comment: Perhaps update the code so that it runs here in the Stack Snippet, currently not outputting the issue.

Comment: I have added the image of the output. I want the pill with 2x at the end of the text in line number 2.

Comment: easier to help if you share working MVCE code